# Find (x,y) subpixel coordinates of a maximum using discrete quadratic interpolation

Tags: c++, interpolation, discrete-mathematics

I have to find the subpixel `(x,y)` coordinates of the maximum value given a set of discrete points.
Im ny case, I run `cv::matchTemplate` function that slides a model window along an image and returns a score value for each pixel position.
The result is an image with the score for each position and the location `(x0, y0)` with of the maximum value, like these values around the maximum value found:

```
      x_1    x0     x1
y_1 |0.91 | 0.89 | 0.90|
y0  |0.92 | 0.99 | 0.89|
y1  |0.95 | 0.95 | 0.90|
```

I would like to use a quadratic interpolation to find where are the subpixel point coordinates of the interpolated maximum value, using just the nearest neighbors.
In a 1d case, I use this formula (assuming `x0` is the origin):

```
interpolated_x = (x_1-x1)/(2.*(x_1-2.*x0+x1));
```

For example:

```
  x_1    x0     x1
|0.92 | 0.99 | 0.89|
```

you get `interpolated_x = -0.08823`, that is correctly slightly on the left of x0.

Is there some C++ code for the 2d case?

Comment: https://github.com/tenomoto/libeno/blob/master/biquadratic.c <- this looks more or less like the interpolation you want, not sure how you would find the point with the maximum, other than some iterative search

Comment: @jakub_d: With a quartic function like that it could be hard, yes.  Are we instead looking for a quadratic *fit* (which would typically not reproduce 9 input points exactly)?